# paperclip works locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, paperclip

I have an app deployed on heroku, in which mongoid-paperclip is used for file management. Everything works locally, but when I push it to Heroku, it crashed.

Here are the logs from LogSets:

```
1 Feb 2016 12:04:09.445  2016-02-01 10:04:09.166406+00:00 app web.1     - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.3/lib/paperclip/deprecations.rb:14:in `active_record_version': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.3/lib/paperclip/deprecations.rb:8:in `check'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/paperclip-4.3.3/lib/paperclip.rb:195:in `has_attached_file'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongoid-paperclip-0.0.10/lib/mongoid_paperclip.rb:103:in `has_mongoid_attached_file'
from /app/app/models/location.rb:26:in `<class:Location>'
from /app/app/models/location.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:3:in `require'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from config.ru:in `new'
from config.ru:in `<main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:155:in `load_rackup'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:99:in `app'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:114:in `load_and_bind'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/single.rb:79:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:214:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.16.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>' Exception Context
```

Please help me out of this, thank you.

Comment: The first line in that error log suggests that the enviroment hasn't been loaded (since it doesn't know about ActiveRecord).    Can you add (in an edit to your question) exactly what you are doing when this error occurs?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, thanks for your reply. I checked it again, it is solved now, and it is actually a version issue, related to rails-api. Looks like rails-api only support active record, not mongoid. I recreated my whole project with `rails new`, and did a gem update of all my local gems, it works now.